# Error on creating pivot table filter in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a filter for my pivot table that will only display "string I want to filter by" in the pivot table, and this is what I currently have based off a similar question:

```
Dim apap As String
apap = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value

Dim Field As PivotField
Set Field = PTable.PivotFields("test")

With Field
.ClearAllFilters
.CurrentPage = apap

End With
PTable.RefreshTable
```

But when I try to run this part of the macro, I get runtime error 1004: unable to set the CurrentPage property of the PivotField class. Any idea on how to fix this? Also I would prefer if I could have a static filter "string I want to filter by" instead of a reference to it but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: `.CurrentPage` may require the sourceName, which may be different from the visible name in the pivot Table (from renaming). Also, spaces (or lack of) makes a difference.

Comment: could you explain what you mean? I'm new to vba, sorry. And where should i add spaces?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear, was I? The issue is most like one of two possiblities: 1) There is no data for that selection. 2) The value in `apap` does not match an option for the filter. The comment about the spaces was in reference to the value held by `apap`. For example, if `apap = "Name "`, but the fieldname was "Name" (no space), you'd get an error.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I was running through the module with F8 and 'apap' has the value of "string i want to filter by" and matches the option I need, but the error still persists, and I just tried to add a space after apap but still no luck.

Comment: And there's no extra white space in the range you're pulling the string from?

Comment: correct, there's no extra white space.